# I'd like a tag dictionary or tag-search function

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

Just a few seconds ago, I posted a question on UX SE. However, being fairly new to the site, I had no clue what tags would best fit my question.

What would be nice is if there was a link next to the word *Tags* that took me to an area that would help me look for tags to use.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the word tags?

Comment: There's a Tags link in the navigation near the top. There's also at least one userscript (SE Tag Suggestions) that will suggest possible tags based on related questions; I would link you to it, but while I have it installed, I can't seem to dig up where I found it.

Answer (score 5):

When you click inside the *Tags* textbox on the *Ask* page, you will see this box on the right side of your screen:

> [image: Tags]

Note the *popular tags >>* link at the bottom? Click there and you will see a list of commonly used tags.

Is this what you had in mind?